# Использование 360 веб-камеры в Unity

Tags: unity3d, видео, обработка-изображений, vr, web-камера

Недавно обзавёлся [360-камерой с двумя объективами](https://www.insta360.com/product/insta360-air). Хочу транслировать изображение с неё в Unity. Т.к. это веб-камера, я использовал класс **WebCamTexture**, чтобы транслировать видео-поток на сферу (камера внутри сферы, у самой сферы полигоны повёрнуты внутрь). Но, к сожалению, столкнулся с вот такими искажениями:[image: Дублирование сбоку][image: Чёрный червяк?][image: Сфера]
Сама камера рассчитана для моб. устройств, её спокойно можно подсоединить к телефону. Скачав приложение и подключив камеру, я заметил, что искажения почти незаметны вследствие, наверное, обработки приложением:
[image: Рука][image: Червяка нет]

Вот и вопрос: как добиться такого качества? Нужны ли какие-то доп. ассеты для Unity? Нужно ли использовать вместо сферы что-нибудь другое, например, встроенный в движок **"Video PLayer"**?

*Заранее благодарен за ответы и комментарии.*
|
|
|
Edit: Хм, я попробовал поместить текстуру на плоскость, и вот что получилось:
[image: Опа]
Что можно с этим сделать? Надо как-то превратить изображение веб-камеры со стереоскопического на моноскопическое.

Comment: Ещё в Интернете полно гайдов по созданию/внедрению/рендерингу 360-видосов в Unity, а про трансляцию видеопотока ничего не могу найти.

Comment: Нашёл один интересный [гайд](http://theta360.guide/community-document/community.html), но там используют для моей проблемы отдельные проги для работ с модельками, как-то разрезая сферу и подгоняя под изображение видео камеры... Неужели ради такой маленькой задачи надо в конец упороться и лезть в какие-то сторонние редакторы? ;(

Comment: Вы использовали стандартную сферу Unity? Она, скажем так, не совсем "правильная". Велика вероятность, что такие артефакты именно из-за этого.

Comment: Иван,нужна Ваша помощь в похожем приложении с передачей изображения. Можете проконсультировать?